# What is the indirect object in "Se tiver alguma dúvida, pergunte a um funcionário"?

Tags: gramática

I am trying to find the indirect object in this sentence:

> "Se tiver alguma dúvida, pergunte a um funcionário."
> *If you have any queries, ask a member of staff.*

My textbook says that the preposition "a" is used before indirect objects but I just don't see how "funcionário" is an indirect object in this case.

Comment: Vlad, if you explain why it doesn't look like an indirect object to you, we'll be able to give you better answers. Perhaps, in your native language it wouldn't be a indirect objetc...

Comment: @Jacinto Good point. So in English the phrase is "If you have any queries, ask a member of staff" And here "you" is the subject of "have any queries", and the understood subject of the imperative clause "ask a member of staff" where "a member of staff" is the direct object because If there is only one object in a clause, it is always a direct one.

Comment: That's definitely not the case in Portuguese: the person you address the question to is always the indirect objet whether an explicit direct object is there or not. I would have thought that's the case in English as well. Say, "She doesn't know Bob is dead? You must tell her" / "you must tell her the news." If you're right, *her* is direct object in the first sentence and indirect object in the second. I find that strange. Well, in Portuguese it would be indirect in both cases.

Comment: There is no indirect object in the question posted in the title. um funcionário (here, an employee) is a direct object. **Ask the employee a question** =here the employee is an indirect object and a question is direct. So, I wonder about your book. These verbs are called ditransitive in English. V+IO+DO versus

Comment: @Lambie, I didn't know English gramar works like that. Always learning! But Portuguese grammar is different, and *ao funcionário* is um objeto indireto. You can check that in any Portuguese gramar. For instance in Cunha e Cintra give the example *perdoem ao pobre tolo*, where *ao pobre tolo* is objeto indireto.

Comment: @Jacinto I guess I become confused when the asker does not make it clear but translates the grammatical category. See what I mean? You will note I was talking about the English. But sure preguntar algo à alguém (indirect).

Comment: @Lambie, yes I get you. Probably not the best idea to use English term to explain Portuguese grammar or vice-versa.

Comment: @Jacinto I think we just need to specify which language That's all.

Answer (score 3):

It is an indirect object because it requires a preposition (*a* in this case). Portuguese and English grammars differ in this respect. They work the same in a sentence like:

> Pergunta **ao João** a morada dela
> Ask **João** her address

Here *ao João* is the indirect object, just as *João* in English (except that Portuguese requires a preposition and English does not), and *a morada dela / her address* is the direct object. The two Languagess differ if the “old direct object” is no longer there explicitly, even though we can understand one implicitly:

> Se queres saber a morada dela, pergunta **ao João** [implicitly understood *a morada dela*]
> If you want to know her address, ask **João**

Here, I’ve now learned, in English grammar *João* is reanalysed as direct object, because the rule is there is an indirect object only if there is a direct one too (although some grammarians admit exceptions). In Portuguese grammar, *ao João* is still the indirect object even with no direct one. The best way to tell in this case is that *ao João* can be replaced with the indirect object pronoun (*lhe*) but not with the direct object pronoun (*o*)

> O João deve saber a morada dela. Pergunta-**lhe** [*lhe* = *a ele*]
> João probably knows her address. Ask **him**

It’s just the same with your example:

> Se tiver alguma dúvida, pergunte **a um funcionário**
> Se tiver alguma dúvida, procure um funcionário e pergunte-**lhe**

It is the other way round with verbs like *interrogar*, which take a direct object only:

> A polícia prendeu **o suspeito** e interrogou-**o**

(You can tell the difference only with the third person: *lhe(s)* ≠ *o*(*s*)/*a*(*s*). For the other persons indirect and direct object pronouns coincide: *me, te, nos, vos*.)

Furthermore, some verbs, like *telefonar*, take an indirect object but cannot take a direct one:

> Espera, tenho de telefonar **ao João**. Ok, telefono-**lhe** mais tarde
> Wait, I have to call João. Ok, I’ll call him later

### Generally: how to identify the indirect object (in most cases)

Generally the Portuguese direct object cannot have a preposition (but there are always exceptions!). So if it has a preposition it is (generally!) an indirect object or it is an adjunct. I’ll now switch to Portuguese terms to make sure there’s no confusion with English grammar. To tell whether a prepositional phrase is an *objeto indireto* or an *adjunto* try and drop it: you can still get a full sentence without the adjunto but not without the objeto indireto: *vou ao cinema à noite*; *vou ao cinema* is still fine because we only dropped the adjunto *à noite*; *vou* or *vou à noite* is not a full sentence because we dropped the objeto indireto *ao cinema*. *Ao cinema* is a type of objeto indireto called *complento oblíquo*. You can tell it because you cannot replace it with the indirect object pronoun: *vou ao cinema* is fine; **vou-lhe* is wrong. If you can make that replacement it is a *complemento indireto*: *telefona ao João, telefona-lhe*. Again, there are a few exceptions to this!

Comment: Thanks a lot! And youre entirely right. I think the confusion might come from a difference in how indirect/direct objects are treated in English v romance languages. In English it is contested whether an implied direct object makes the only object of a sentence an indirect object or not, while in Portuguese that isnt the case

Comment: The first answer here shows the difference: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203125/can-a-sentence-have-an-indirect-object-without-a-direct-object

Comment: @Vlad-zlietski, I've reformulated the answer, addressing the diference between Portuguese and English gramars early on, and added a short how-to-tell-indirect objects-from-other-things in Portuguese. To keek it short I had to overlook exceptions, sorry.

Comment: Ask João whether Ana is coming. What is indirect in Portuguese, is direct in English. See   it here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ask Transitive: ask somebody if, whether, etc… She asked her boss whether she could have the day off.

Comment: @Lambie, ok I've now replaced all those se/whether-clauses with noun phrases, and my example and English translation are perfectly parallel... so much simpler.

Comment: Great idea, really.